# Edge bipartization with equal number of nodes

Tags: graph, bipartite

I'm trying to solve the standard bipartization problem, i.e., find a subset of the edges such that the output graph is a bipartite graph.
My additional constraints are:

1. The number of vertices on each side must be equal.
2. Each vertex has exactly 1 edge.

In fact, it would suffice to know whether such a subset exists at all - I don't really need the construction itself.
Optimally, the algorithm should be fast as I need to run it for O(400) nodes repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

If each vertex is to be incident on exactly one edge, it seems what you want is a matching.  If so, Edmonds's blossom algorithm will do the job.  I haven't used an implementation of the algorithm to recommend.  You might check out http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/leda/ledak/index.htm